# How would I be able to retrieve the all the values of a specific key from a HashMap?

Tags: java

I am supposed to implement the following shown in the comments. I am new to Java and created the code below, however, it doesn't compile. What is the proper way to do this?

```
 /**
 * Retrieve the names of all passengers of the flight with id 'id'.
 * If 'id' a non-existing flight id, then return an empty list.
 * @param id id of some flight
 * @return List of names of passengers whose flight has id 'id'
 */
public ArrayList<String> getPassengerNames(Integer id) {
    if(passengers.containsKey(id)) {
        ArrayList<String> valuesFromMap = passengers.values();
        return valuesFromMap;
    }else {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the HashMap defined?

Comment: Shouldn't a `HashMap` return *one* value per key?

Comment: *however, it doesn't compile* What is the error message and how is the map defined?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your HashMap maps each id to an ArrayList

Instead of:

```
ArrayList<String> valuesFromMap = passengers.values();
```

You need to use:

```
ArrayList<String> valuesFromMap = passengers.get(id);
```

This will retrieve the list of passengers with this flight id.